Trying to get data from Odoo using PHP/Laravel-9 using XMLRPC need help and guidance
I am able to authenticate but when trying to get data its giving me error
enter image description here
This is the error I am getting
Is there anyone who can help me to resolve this issue quickly please.
I am using Laravel version 9.46, check using via php artisan -v
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use PhpXmlRpc\Client;
use PhpXmlRpc\Request;
use PhpXmlRpc\Value;
use DB;

class FetchOdooData extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'fetch:odoo-data';
    protected $description = 'Fetch data from Odoo and update local database';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // Odoo credentials

        $url = 'http://urltoodoo::8049';
        $db = 'DBNAME';
        $username = 'username';
        $password = 'APIKEY';


        // Define XML-RPC endpoints
        $common_url = "{$url}/xmlrpc/2/common";
        $object_url = "{$url}/xmlrpc/2/object";

        // Create a client instance for common services
        $client = new Client($common_url);

        // Prepare the authentication request
        $request = new Request('authenticate', array(
            new Value($db, 'string'),
            new Value($username, 'string'),
            new Value($password, 'string'),
            new Value(array(), 'struct')
        ));

        // Send the authentication request
        $response = $client->send($request);

        //var_dump($response);

        if ($response->faultCode()) {
            $this->error('Error: ' . $response->faultString());
            return;
        }

        // Retrieve the user ID from the response
        $user_id = $response->value()->scalarval();

        if ($user_id) {
            $this->info("Authenticated successfully. User ID: $user_id");
        } else {
            $this->error("Authentication failed.");
            return;
        }

        // Function to call Odoo methods
        function callOdooMethod($client, $method, $params) {
            var_dump($method);
            var_dump($params);
            var_dump($client);
            
            $msg = new Request($method, array(new Value($params, 'array')));

            var_dump($msg);

            $resp = $client->send($msg);
            
            var_dump($resp);

            if ($resp->faultCode()) {
                return 'Error: ' . $resp->faultString();
            }
            return $resp->value();
        }

        // Fetch last sync time for a model
        function getLastSyncTime($model_name) {
            return DB::table('last_sync')->where('model_name', $model_name)->value('last_update');
        }

        // Update last sync time for a model
        function updateLastSyncTime($model_name) {
            DB::table('last_sync')->updateOrInsert(
                ['model_name' => $model_name],
                ['last_update' => now()]
            );
        }

        // Fetch data from Odoo
        function fetchData($models, $db, $user_id, $password, $model_name, $fields, $last_sync_time=0) {
            //$domain = $last_sync_time ? [['write_date', '>', $last_sync_time]] : [];
            $params = array(
                new Value($db, 'string'),
                new Value($user_id, 'int'),
                new Value($password, 'string'),
                new Value($model_name, 'string'),
                new Value('search_read', 'string'),
                new Value(array(
                    //new Value($domain, 'array'), // Domain filter
                    new Value($fields, 'array'), // Fields to retrieve
                ), 'array')
            );

            return callOdooMethod($models, 'execute_kw', $params);
        }

        // Update local database with fetched data
        function updateLocalDatabase($model_name, $data) {
            foreach ($data as $record) {

            }
        }

        // Create a client instance for object services
        $models = new Client($object_url);

        var_dump($models);

        // Define fields to retrieve for each model
        $project_fields = array('name', 'user_id', 'date_start', 'date_end', 'tasks');
        $task_fields = array('name', 'user_id', 'date_deadline', 'stage_id', 'description');
        $ticket_fields = array('name', 'stage_id', 'user_id', 'priority', 'description');
        $incident_fields = array('name', 'stage_id', 'user_id', 'priority', 'description'); // Replace with actual fields

        // Define models
        $models_to_fetch = array(
            'project.project' => $project_fields,
            'project.task' => $task_fields,
            'helpdesk.ticket' => $ticket_fields
        );

        /*,
            'your_incident_model_name' => $incident_fields // Replace with actual model name */

        foreach ($models_to_fetch as $model_name => $fields) {
            //$last_sync_time = getLastSyncTime($model_name);
            $data = fetchData($models, $db, $user_id, $password, $model_name, $fields); //, $last_sync_time

            if (is_string($data)) {
                $this->error("Error fetching $model_name: " . $data);
            } else {
                $this->info(ucfirst(str_replace('.', ' ', $model_name)) . " Data:\n");
                print_r($data);
                updateLocalDatabase($model_name, $data);
                updateLastSyncTime($model_name);
            }
        }
    }
}

I am using "phpxmlrpc/phpxmlrpc": "^4.10" package
Can anyone help me get authenticate and get the tickets and tasks data from odoo

Given the error message and the code, it looks like in the line new Value($fields, 'array') in the fetchData method, $fields is an array of plain php strings. It should be an array of XmlRpc\Value objects.
You can either do that conversion manually, or simplify your code by having recursive wrapping of native php values into XmlRpc\Value objects by using XmlRpc\Encoder::encode() method, as seen f.e. in https://github.com/gggeek/phpxmlrpc/blob/master/demo/client/proxy.php
